# 2d dynamic associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

Is it possible to make something like this:

```
var fieldObjArray = Array();;

    for(var k in SpesificPropertiesInfo){
        var fieldTable = createFieldTable(SpesificPropertiesInfo[k]);
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['fieldStatus'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldStatus;
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['fieldName'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName;
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['columnName'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].columnName;
    }
```

I want to create an array that it first dimensions is an associative one (and dynamic // i do not know its name at the beginning), the second dimensions is an associative but i do know it's name.

Comment: use Object that`s all :)

Comment: @VladIoffe Why do you need it to be an array?

Comment: I will correct my self, I need an array of this objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is.

However, use objects, not arrays.
Arrays in JS are ***only*** for `0...n` indices, and don't work properly with `for ... in`, either.

```
var myObj = {},

    key = "",
    val = "";

for (key in yourObj) {
    if (yourObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        val = yourObj[key];
        myObj[val.fieldname] = {
            fieldStatus: val.fieldStatus,
            fieldName: val.fieldName,
            colName: val.colName
        };

        //...
    }
}
```

You now have a `myObj` which has all of `yourObj`'s primary indices, each one an object, containing the properties of the second dimension...

Comment: thanks, but is there any way to make it as I asked (associative)?

Comment: How is this not associative?  If you do what *you* want, a) performance will hugely decrease (JS engines will turn Array back into an Object...), Array-based methods like `splice` will break, loops using `for (i=0;...)` will break, and you'll start ending up getting Array method names in your results...  What exact functionality are you looking for, here?

Comment: var fieldObjArray = new Array();

    for(var k in SpesificPropertiesInfo){
        var fieldTable = createFieldTable(SpesificPropertiesInfo[k]);
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName] = new Array();
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['fieldStatus'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldStatus;
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['fieldName'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName;
        fieldObjArray[SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].fieldName]['columnName'] = SpesificPropertiesInfo[k].columnName;
           }

Comment: sorry for this answer (my reputation is to low to make an answer to my own question). if someone can do this for me it would be nice. you can see the answer to my question above (it worked for me). thank you all

Comment: ...yes...  ...then JS treats it like an object, except that when you do lookups of your properties, you'll also get `pop`, `push`, `shift`, `unshift`, `splice`, `length`, `map`, `reduce`, `forEach`, et cetera...  ...what exactly are you looking for? You can force it to behave that way, but then as soon as you start doing `for(k in myArray) { ... }` you're going to have another SO question, because you keep trying to access properties of functions...

Comment: Okay. Just understand that your solution is incorrect, and will break on you, the second you use `for (key in arr)`, or try to use Array methods, and that the person who told you that JS uses associative arrays was 120% incorrect. 2x if they're a teacher/blogger.

Comment: Open your code up in IE8 or FF3 and do a `for (key in fieldObjArray) { console.log(key); }`  You get ***ALL*** of the functions that arrays have as built-in methods in your log.  Which means that if you are passing this object to a function, you're passing those functions in with the properties. Better yet: `var myAssocArr = []; myAssocArr["name"] = "Bob"; myAssocArr["age"] = 32; myAssocArr.length; // 0` Your array's length is the highest initialized index in the array, you haven't put anything in a number, therefore, it's still at 0. Meanwhile, `var bob = {}; bob["name"] = "Bob";` works fine.

Comment: now I have this issue: after I have done the solution @Norguard gave my how should I pass this Array in $.ajax (jquery)? should I do JSON.stringify(myObj) and than pass it?

Comment: Sure. Or if you're using objects, you can still build a string of parameters by using `for (key in obj){ if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { queryParam = key; queryValue = obj[key]; }}` Or just `JSON.stringify();` and set that value to a query parameter.